# How to join three tables using LINQ with mutually exclusive foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm banging my head against a wall for this one... my SQL isn't the best, so I can't solve it, and couldn't find an answer to this question...

The question is: how to join three tables using Query Syntax (LINQ) if the Keys of the intermediate table are exclusive? What I mean is... I have Table A that has a Foreign Key pointing to B... B has a foreign key pointing to A, and another to C... And C points to B. In Table B, if FK to A isn't null, then FK to C is null (and vice versa) and there is a linking key between these relationship.

It is like if key to A is entrance, and key to B is exiting, and Linking Key is a product. They cant be in the same line, but two different movements have the same product. The objective is to get info about A + B + C.

For example, with these tables:

[image: Tables Example]

If I wanted to know about (Table A) ID = 'a' info, then the query should give back

[image]

Or something that could be worked after to give something like that...

I have:

```
vM_Report_Aux = (from ctbr in db.Rec_Cont_Mov
                 join rM in db.Rec_Mov on ctbr.Rec_ContabID equals rM.Rec_ContabID
                 join brm in db.Rec_B_Mov on rM.RecID equals bRM.RecID

                 select new 
                         {
                            ID = ctbr.ID,
                            Val = rM.Val
                         }).OrderBy(q => q.ID).ToList();
```

This query returns null... if I take one join it gives me half of the results (Table A, for example)... If I take the other (and adjust the query), it returns the other half (table C). In both, table B is shown...

Is there any way of doing this, and get the expected result?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you haven't got foreign keys here, but fields that happen to have identical values in different tables. Esp. table B and table C can't be joined like that (based on the content you show). Please show the table definitions (DDL). Apart from that, maybe it's just me, but I don't understand a word of your description. A linking key between relationships? What is a "movement", a "product"?

Comment: Thanks for reply Gert... They are foreign Keys... Why can't B and C be joined? I have a working query that joins them successfuly. I just cant join the three simultaniously..

About the description: For example, if you have to manage stocks of products you can have a table for movements where you register buys and sells. You can Buy a product, wich inserts 1 mov in table. Or sell and insert another mov to table. How does a report knows what is the stock at given time of a specific product? Because product ID is the "linkingKey" between all moves. That's what I ment. Not clear?

Comment: I only see `F.Key W` as fields with common data in tables B and C. In neither of them this field is an alternate key (i.e unique). That's why you can't join them. Sure, you can *technically* but the join is a meaningless Cartesian Product. And no, it's not clear. You have a description, data and code. These three parts aren't related in any way and full of cryptic abbreviations.